# Vim with python support enviromental variables

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, omnicomplete

If i type in the vim command line

```
:python import os;print os.getenv('PYTHONPATH')
```

I get a path
If i close vim and on the same terminal do

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

I get another completly different path
Why is this, where is vim getting this path?
This is relevant because the autocompletion can't find the modules thus it doesnt work.
I know this because if i try, again from the vim cli

```
:python import django
```

It fails
But if i exit vim and type

```
python
>>> import django
```

No errors are shown!
Whats going on here?
I'm using virtualenv and i checked the activate source and is not changing the PYTHONPATH.
I tried this without virtualenv, same problem.

Update:
The line i used to configure the Vim source prior to compiling it

> ./configure --prefix=${HOME}/apps/vim73 --with-features=huge
>   --enable-gui=gnome2 --enable-pythoninterp --enable-rubyinterp
>   --enable-multibyte --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.6/config

Comment: what happens if you type `echo $PYTHONPATH` inside the shell? Python also looks for modules outside PYTHONPATH in `sys.path`, i.e. you could try to test that in both cases and see if it's the same

Comment: Inside Vim !echo $PYTHONPATH is the same result as the getenv result, quitting vim and doing $echo $PYTHONPATH gives a different path.

Comment: yes, but the python in vim is primarely made to include a Python interface to vim, i.e. in vimrc for instance, this will probably work inside vim `import vim` but it will probably fail outside vim. do you get autocompletion only for modules which can be found inside the `PYTHONPATH` reported by vim?

Comment: Yes, exactly only on the PYTHONPATH that Vim sees. Vim is ignoring the PYTHONPATH active on the terminal running it.
I don't think the configure line i used while compiling vim has anything to do with it, but i added it to the question for good measure.

Answer (score 4):

`PYTHONPATH` is a red herring: that's not what the virtualenv uses to configure itself. The virtualenv works by adding a prefix to `PATH` that points to the location of an alternate `python` executable, overriding the system `python`.

The problem with Vim is that the Python embedding does not look at the Python executable or `PATH`: it looks for and loads the `libpython` library, which virtualenv does not virtualize. This means that Vim will always initialize the system Python, regardless of any virtualenv.

However, all is not lost: Vim can still run the virtualenv's initialization script after its own Python initialization. Jeremy Cantrell wrote a Vim plugin to help automate this, which should solve your problem:

- https://github.com/jmcantrell/vim-virtualenv